# only able to use dbcontext once before it disposes

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dbcontext

I'm working on a site in asp.net core 3.1 and I'm trying to read the database twice in the page model. However, I'm getting a "System.OnbjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object" error. This is a snippet of my Index.cshtml.cs

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly DocsiteContext _context;

    public IndexModel(DocsiteContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public Document CurrDocument;

    public void OnGet()
    {
        FunctionA();
    }

    private async void FunctionA()
    {
        List<string> AllDocs = await _context.Documents.OrderBy(d => d.FileName).Select(d => d.FileName).ToListAsync();
        FunctionB();
    }

    private async void FunctionB()
    {
        CurrDocument = await _context.Documents.FirstOrDefaultAsync(f => f.FileName == CurrPath && !f.IsDirectory);
    }
}`
```

And this is a snippet of the the Startup.cs class

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddRazorPages();

        services.AddDbContext<DocsiteContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DocsiteContext")));
    }
```

I know the context disposes after the first use, but I'm unsure how to keep it to use the second time.
I'm pretty new to asp.net, so if this is the wrong approach I would love some suggestions!

Comment: Have you tried to turn on MultipleActiveResultSets in your connection string? In case if it's mssql

Comment: You're returning a void instead of a Task. There's a chance that your class is getting destroyed before requesting the second connection in FunctionB, hence the disposed error. Also, I'm not sure if the context would dispose after first use. It would die whenever the class gets disposed.

Comment: Oh  I see! I added the Task return (I already had MultipleActiveResultSets turned on) and that worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A DbContext is a "scoped" service. This means that a new dbContext is created for each HTTP request. If you do something like redirect to another page, you'll get a new dbContext object.